# Not able to understand the inner working of the Python Generator

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to understand the bytecode for the generator and internally how it works but it is very confusing. Can someone please explain how this works.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqEGI.png

Moreover, when I tried
`x = (i for i in [1,2])`
`x.__code__`
I got this error
`AttributeError: generator object has no attribute __code__`
If this doesn't work then he can we see code object lists like `co_names, co_consts` etc.

Comment: Please edit the question properly and please paste the code patch in here

Answer (score 0):

With the `dis` module you can display the assembly:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis((i for i in [1,2]))
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    2 FOR_ITER                10 (to 14)
              4 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
              8 YIELD_VALUE
             10 POP_TOP
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
        >>   14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```